# TYPO3 7.6: how to add php content to a page

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I am responsible for a webpage which is using Typo3, which I did not create. Recently (and with assistance), the version of Typo3 was upgraded from 6.2 to 7.6. Since then, I have lost the possibility to include php code directly in a page, in the backend (in the same way you would add text, or images, or html). As far as I can tell, there used to be an extension to do h (php_page_content) which is not compatible with this latest version.

I have seen some examples on how to proceed on the internet (for example at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html), but this is fairly advanced for me, and I am unable to apply this to my problem (my skills in php are pretty much non-existent). Can someone provide assistance in this matter?

Comment: Did you tried with user function?

Comment: Well, I read that it would be the way to go, but I have no clue how to do it in practice. If you have the time, can you give me an example? or point towards one?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the simple stuff might be help you,
try this, its working for me

**Setup.ts**

```
# Add bellow typoscrip in setup.ts
lib.content = USER
lib.content {

    # Define external PHP Script file path
    includeLibs = fileadmin/function.php

    # Call user function
    userFunc = getData->GetNewsCountInCat

    # Pass your argument to the php scrpt (Here function.php)
    value = This is the value
}
```

**function.php**

Your PHP logic goes Here (Path: fileadmin/).

```
class getData
{
    // Initialise cObject
    public $cObj;

    public function GetNewsCountInCat($content, $conf=array()) {
    
        // Get argument
        $arg = $this->cObj->TEXT($conf);
        echo $arg;
    }
}
```

Now you can access lib object in your html with:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content" />
```

Your output will be:

```
This is the value.
```

However, `includeLibs` has removed from TYPO3 version 8. You can use USER and USER_INT with a higher version. Find the URL below:

URL: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/7.6/en-us/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html

Greetings!

Comment: I think that includeLibs is deprecated in TYPO3 7.6 and removed in 8. Is there any way you could modify or add addtional notes here to help us understand how to make this future proof?

Comment: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use few available extensions like
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/pe_pagephpcontentelement